# why does my use of the saltstack apache-formula fail to set the 'id' variable

Tags: python, saltstack

why does my use of the saltstack apache-formula fail to set the 'id' variable ? my code is as fallows ?

```
apache:
    sites:

        changed.com:

            template_file: salt://salt/formulas/salt/apache-formula/apache/vhosts/standard.tmpl
            template_engine: jinja

            interface: '*'
            port: '80'

           ServerName: {{ id }}
           ServerAdmin: webmaster@{{ id }}
           LogLevel: Debug
           ErrorLog: {{ logdir }}/{{ id }}-error.log

           WSGIScriptAlias: / /var/www/project2/django.wsgi
```

the error message is as fallows:

```
Rendering SLS "base:netchosis" failed: Jinja variable 'id' is undefined; line 15


        port: '80'

        ServerName: {{ id }}
        ServerAdmin: webmaster@{{ id }}
        LogLevel: Debug 
        ErrorLog: {{ logdir }}/{{ id }}-error.log    <======================

        WSGIScriptAlias: / /var/www/project2/django.wsgi
```

I was expecting "changed.com" as the ID thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either! I've been trying to learn Saltstack but I'm afraid I should have gone with something else instead. Basic stuff works, but then when you're trying to pick up those popular "formulas" it doesn't really work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The example pillar file is here: https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula/blob/master/pillar.example

I'd suggest using 2 spaces per indentation level and make sure they line up.